# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [31765820, 400]

Tags: python, arrays, svm, cross-validation, valueerror

I was developing a Support Vector Classifier (SVC), a sub of SVM Model with 400 sound training data, 50 words and each word includes 8 audio (*.wav) file. The Validation function used was Cross Validation with 5-fold, so the model has 80% training data and 20% testing data.

I was some difficulties in reading the training data. The read_training_data function was executed completely, but when I call the cross-validation or fitting training data to model, the error was shown, like this "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [31765820, 400]"

Each sound data have a length about 109.440 - 165.000 in approx. When I found that error, I think the second loop in read_training_data function was reading all data, resulting 31.765.820 length.
And actually, all I want is the second loop was reading each audio file, with a length about 109.000 - 165.000, not like this.

I was so stuck on handling this, please help me, any help will so worthy to me. Thank You :)

Here was the code of read training data

```
def read_training_data(training_directory):
    target_data = []
    sound_data = []
    # sound_col = []

    for each_word in words:
        for each in [0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8]:
            sound_path = os.path.join(training_directory, each_word, each_word + '_' 
                                  + str(each) + '.wav')
            sound_read = wave.open(sound_path,'r')
        
            target_data.append(each_word)

            length = sound_read.getnframes()
            for i in range (length):
                waveData = sound_read.readframes(1)
                data = struct.unpack("<1h", waveData)
                sound_data.append(data)
            
            # sound_data = np.reshape(sound_data, (1, 109440), order='C')
        
    return (pygame.sndarray.array(sound_data), np.array(target_data))
```

Here is the read_training_data declaration. The error was not shown here, but later in cross-validation declaration.

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"))

training_dataset_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'train_sound_mono')

sound_data, target_data = read_training_data(training_dataset_dir)
```

Here is the SVC declaration

```
svc_model = LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge', dual=True, tol=1e-4, 
                  C=1.0, multi_class='ovr', fit_intercept=True, 
                  intercept_scaling=1, class_weight='balanced', verbose=0, 
                  random_state=None, max_iter=1000)
```

Here is the Cross-Validation Declaration

```
def cross_validation(model, num_of_fold, train_data, train_label):
    accuracy_result = cross_val_score(model, train_data, train_label,
                                  cv=num_of_fold)
    print("Cross Validation Result for ", str(num_of_fold), " -fold")

    print(accuracy_result * 100)
```

And here was the error exist

```
cross_validation(svc_model, 5, sound_data, target_data)
```

Here is the explanation

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-c52e00174535> in <module>()
----> 1 cross_validation(svc_model, 5, sound_data, target_data)

4 frames

<ipython-input-7-1ddf14b25404> in cross_validation(model, num_of_fold, train_data, train_label)
      1 def cross_validation(model, num_of_fold, train_data, train_label):
      2     accuracy_result = cross_val_score(model, train_data, train_label,
----> 3                                       cv=num_of_fold)
      4     print("Cross Validation Result for ", str(num_of_fold), " -fold")
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    388                                 fit_params=fit_params,
    389                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
--> 390                                 error_score=error_score)
    391     return cv_results['test_score']
    392 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    219 
    220     """
--> 221     X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    222 
    223     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    246     """
    247     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 248     check_consistent_length(*result)
    249     return result
    250 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [31765820, 400]
```

And is code throw the same error too

```
svc_model.fit(sound_data, target_data)
```

Any help will be worthy to me. Thank You So Much for any cooperation

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily due to the shape of the arrays not being similar. Please check the arrays with `sound_data.shape` and `target_data.shape`. Then use the `reshape` method or split them properly so that the shapes match.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've already tried but when I called `sound_data.shape` the error rises like this `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`. I know it shapes was a list, and it automatically generated in the second loop, what must I do? I was so stuck because from first time I code, the shape was list, or ndarray object, on any code I try, and any library I've tried (SciPy, or wave this time). and once again, thankyou...